# x-editable inputs aren't shown properly with resizable columns

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable, bootstrap-table

I use bootstrap 3 and have a [bootstrap-table](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) table with editable cells and resizable columns. For resizing I use extension [bootstrap-table-resizable](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-resizable) and for cells editing [bootstrap-table-editable](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-editable)

When I don't use resizable plugin I can edit cells and see whole editable input.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L7vgcx0/42/)

[image]

When I use resizable plugin, only part of editable input is visible.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L7vgcx0/44/)

[image]

When I want to edit cells, I would like to see the whole input. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543142/x-editable-popover-not-shown-completely) post and tried to set `z-index, overflow` properties or `container: 'body'` for editable plugin, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there's any native method, but this might be used as a simple workaround.

The idea is to set a `width` style of the corresponding (on given index) `<th>` element, when a click event on `.editable` element is detected:

```
$('.editable').click(function(){
    // change the <td> width only if it's less than '.editable-container' width
    if($(this).next().width() > $(this).closest('td').width()){
        $('th:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').css('width', $(this).next().width()+15);
    }
});
```

**Note**:
`$(this).next()` points to the `.editable-container` *span* element which holds the input field and <kbd>✔</kbd><kbd>✖</kbd> buttons.

---

Then use editable's `hidden` event to reset the width of `<th>` again to `auto`:

```
$('.editable').on('hidden', function() {
    $('th:eq('+$(this).closest('td').index()+')').css('width', 'auto'); 
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bquexnnL/)

Comment: Glad I could help :-)